# Cocos2d alternative to SpriteKit

Tags: ios, iphone, cocos2d-iphone, sprite-kit

I can't find an alternative in Cocos2d documentation to

```
SKPhysicsBody bodyWithPolygonFromPath
```

and

```
SKShapeNode
```

There's a way to write something similar for cocos2d ? I can't find nothing in internet... I'm transforming a SpriteKit project in a Cocos project and this two objects are foundamental for my game...

EDIT

i'm using cocos2d V3.1

Comment: SKPhysicsBody  = CCPhysicsSprite or CCSprite with b2body.  SKShapeNode = b2shape.

Comment: ok can you provide two simple example so i can mark your answer as correct?

Answer (score 1):

SKPhysicsBody in Cocos2D V3.1 would be CCPhysicsBody http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/docs/api/Classes/CCPhysicsBody.html